# Does the EFI boot partition need to be the first partition?

Tags: windows-8, uefi, debian-wheezy

I'm trying to install kubuntu 13.04 and debian wheezy on my laptop with UEFI on. The installation goes fine but when I reboot it shows "no OS found". Could it be because I already have windows 8 on `/dev/sda1`?

My partitions are :

`/dev/sda1` containing Windows 8 installation. This is not UEFI installation. This partition includes boot files for Windows 8 as well (I haven't created separate boot partition for Windows 8).

And I have `/dev/sda2` as NTFS for music files storage.

Now for UEFI installation I created 500MB `/dev/sda3` as "efi-boot".

Then created `/dev/sda4` for root file system and installed the kubuntu 13.04 but it failed to boot after installation. Tried debian wheezy as well with the same result.

What's wrong with my partitions. Does the efi-boot partition needs to be `/dev/sda1` for UEFI installation. Or am I missing something with this process?

Comment: Have you formatted your EFI partition as FAT and have you registered it with the UEFI so that it's recognized as a EFI boot partition? ALso, were you able to boot Windows 8 successfully using just one partition?

Comment: It didn't format it but as i selected the partition to use as efi-boot while installing linux it automatically got formatted with fat32. I don't know how to register it with UEFI . I'm able to boot windows8 only when disabling the UEFI in bios (and yes with single partition).

Comment: If Windows is booting in BIOS mode, then the partition table must be of the MBR variety. I haven't done extensive testing of this, but some EFIs refuse to boot in EFI mode from MBR disks, so that could be your problem. Overall, there are enough unknowns that it's not worth speculating further. Instead, please run [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) on the system and post a link to the `RESULTS.txt` file that it produces. This will eliminate ambiguity and perhaps enable us to suggest solutions.

Comment: Yes the partition table is of MBR type. I will run the boot info script and post the results.

Comment: Ok. Here is the boot info script result. http://pastebin.com/Wa2YanLb

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I got it working. The problem is the hard disk partition table should be of GPT type. I backed up the entire hard disk and converted it to GPT and it worked fine. I also got windows 8 installation booting up in EFI mode. Thanks for the suggestions.

For those who try to install windows 8 in EFI mode from USB stick, it works fine if the USB stick partition table is GPT type and partition formatted as FAT32. Then copy all files from windows 8 ISO to that USB drive and it will be ready to install windows 8 in UEFI mode.